# If statement with and won't work?

Tags: php

Very stupid question, i am C# kid, i also programming 4 years in php, but sometimes if statement won't work when i use 'and' or '&&' inside.

For example current problem is this:

```
    while($row = $res->fetch()){
        if(($row['Season'] != "2015/2016") && ($row['Source'] != "xmlsoccer")){ 
        $i3++; if($i3==1)hisHeader();
        $eventy = $row['HomeTeam'] . '-v-' . $row['AwayTeam'];
        $stagey = $row['League'];

        $datetime = new DateTime($row['Date']);
        $la_time = new DateTimeZone($zone);
        $datetime->setTimezone($la_time);
        $date = $datetime->format('Y-m-d');
        $time = $datetime->format('H:i');

        $url = toAscii($eventy) . "/" . toAscii($stagey) . "/"  . code36($row['HisID']);
        echo "<tr class='brown' style='height:20px;'>" , "<td style='width:120px; border:1px solid #444;'>" , "<matches-list>" , $date , "</matches-list>" , "</td>" , "<td style='width:60px; border:1px solid #444;'>" , "<matches-list>" , $time , "</matches-list>" , "</td>" , "<td class='nav' style='border:1px solid #444;'>" , "<matches-list>" , "<a href='".$url."' title='$matchtitle'>" ,$row['EventName'] ," (<span style='color:#555'>{$row['League']}</span>)", "</matches-list>","</td>";
        if($row['Status'] != 0){    
          echo "<td style='width:60px; border:1px solid #444;'>", "<matches-list>" , 
          $row['HalfTimeHomeGoals'] . ' : ' . $row['HalfTimeAwayGoals'], "</matches-list>", "</td>", 
          "<td style='width:60px; border:1px solid #444; color: #007AFF'>","<matches-list>" , 
          $row['HomeGoals'] . ' : ' . $row['AwayGoals'], "</matches-list>","</td></tr>";
      }
      else{
        echo "<td style='width:60px; border:1px solid #444; color: #777777' colspan='2' style='text-align:center !important;'>",
        "<matches-list>", "NO RESULTS YET" ,"</matches-list>","</td>";
      }
    }
    }
    echo "</tbody></table>";
}
```

Why

```
if(($row['Season'] != "2015/2016") && ($row['Source'] != "xmlsoccer")){
```

won't work? I have millions rows in database and i don't want xmlsoccer data for 2015/2016, but when i run this it returns nothing.

When i remove just this `&& ($row['Source'] != "xmlsoccer")` everything works fine.

I am 100% sure that is everything correct, for example when i dump

```
var_dump($row['Season'] . " " . $row['Source']);
```

it returns for example, '2013/2014' 'xmlsoccer', but nothing inside if statement...

Comment: Sure you have `Source` key? Not `source` or `SOURCE`

Comment: And btw - you'd better select needed data with mysql using `where` instead of filtering results.

Comment: Keep in mind the Chasles relation, I guess you should use `||` **OR** operator instead.

Comment: @Zeratops With OR works, but why? Why AND not works? I want just rows who are not 2015/2016 and xmlsoccer so it is really strange why OR works.

Comment: I always solve it by using OR, but i never realize why? If you can please answer this why should i use OR instead AND in logic AND situations like this where i want rows what are Season NOT 2015/2016 AND Source NOT xmlsoccer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind the Chasles relation. So to explain, let's do some mathematics :

`if(a && b)` can be associated in :

> if **a** and **b** is true so result is true

But if you need to invert this you will think of :

`if(not a and not b)` which will be represented like following :

> if (**a** and **b** is not true so c is true)

But we can translate this last sentence with the Chasles theorm that says :

`A + B = C`

`(A + B)\ = C`

so with Chasles relation the result is

`A\ . B\ = C` (the dot means `OR`)

Which corresponds to **A || B = C**

So we can say that `(A + B)\ = C` is equivalent to `A\ + B\ = C` which means in programming :

**`! (a && b)` is true** is equivalent to  **`!a || !b` is also true**

Finally you can write those 2 conditions that are the sames :

1. `if( ! ( $row['Season'] == "2015/2016") && $row['Source'] == "xmlsoccer" ) )`
2. `if( $row['Season'] != "2015/2016") || $row['Source'] != "xmlsoccer" )`

Comment: If someone can add a link to English Chasles relation, I only found a wikipedia page for my native language.

Comment: A pleasure, I tackled this problem one billions times so If it can helps !

Answer (score 0):

Firstly filter on the SQL layer, it should then return only what you need.
Secondly you clearly ask for everything that isn't xmlsoccer

```
($row['Source'] != "xmlsoccer")
```

But you are confused when you dump the values that you see "2013/2014" and "xmlsoccer" and dont go into the if statement.
From what I understand from your question you want everything that is "xmlsoccer" from every season except '2015/2016'

I think you are looking for this if statement:

```
if(($row['Season'] != "2015/2016") && ($row['Source'] == "xmlsoccer")){
```

Comment: I want all Seasons from all Sources except 2015/2015 and xmlsoccer, so i don't want 2015/2016 AND don't want xmlsoccer. I want 2015/2016 and tipgin for example, or 2013/2014 and xmlsoccer or tipgin. OR doing job, but WHY?

Comment: Ok I think I understand it now, you wanted both of these value but not when these values are combined. I see someone else already answered your question better than I probably could so I wont go any further into this.